# Mac OS X Finder - Creating New Folder with Right-Click in List View

Tags: macos, finder

I am aware that when using Finder in List view, I can create a new folder by right-clicking on an empty row, and pressing 'New Folder'.

However, when I happen to be browsing a folder with quite a lot of files (or just enough to invoke a scrollbar), there are no blank rows, and hence nowhere that I can right-click to create a new folder.

This is not a big problem, I am just a whinger who likes consistency and find this frustrating. Yes, I am aware that I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, or can simply change the Finder view. BUT, is there a way to do this within list view? Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: oh, and I'm using Snow Leopard (version 10.6) :)

Comment: This is a ridiculous hole in the UI. Why, Apple? Why??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not that it gets you exactly what you want, but besides the 4 items listed by Xetius, you can also add a little "create a new folder" icon to the top of your finder window (picture of a folder with a plus sign in the upper right corner).  You would use "View/Customize Tool Bar ..." to add such an icon.

Comment: awesome ! But could it be possible to create the new folder inside the one that is selected ?

Comment: Using the finder, I don't see a way to create a folder inside of a selected folder without first navigating into that selected folder.

Answer (score 7):

Appear to not be.

You can, as you mention, do one of the following:

- Press Shift+Cmd+N
- Change Finder View
- File->New Folder
- New Folder from the Action button on the Toolbar (The gear button)

But you cannot seem to right click (Option-click) anywhere to bring up the context menu with the New Folder option.

Answer (score 2):

Cmd + right click will do it seems. Mine is Yosemite.